# How can I make a Java Script to redirect to another domain?

Tags: javascript, http, url, redirect, dns

my name is Angel and I am not a programmer nor do I have previous experience with any language, today I have noticed that a forum to which I belong bought a new domain, but there is a problem with cookies, since it is not possible to log in if accessed from the new domain.

Many users have had this problem and I wanted to try to make a java script to solve this problem, but the furthest I got was that any web page was redirected to the forum home page, reloading over and over again.

I'm not good at programming, but Javascript has piqued my interest, because of the ease of transforming it into a browser extension.

What I mean is redirect from:

forum.free.com/discussion/8873

to

cooldomain.com/discussion/8873

and that every url with the domain "forum.free.com" redirects to the same page, only with the new domain of "cooldomain.com"

I know that it is a simple script and that it is too much to ask, but the intention is to learn through the use of annotations the reason for each line and to help the users of said forum.

Thank you.

This is the "script" i "made":

```
switch(window.location.hostname){
   case "forum.free.com":
      window.location.replace("cooldomain.com");
      break;
   ...
}
```

Comment: window.location = "http://example.com";

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
<script language=javascript>
function redirect(){
  window.location = "http://cooldomain.com/discussion/8873";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, but how would the script know the domain from which it should redirect, and the "example.com", should it be replaced by the destination or initial web?

Comment: Oh sorry, should have been more descriptive. Yes, you need to write this code from the portal from which you want to redirect the user and the example.com is to be replaced by the destination URL. Edited my answer. :)